# Bootstrap Mega Menu Not Working Offline

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a Mega menu in Bootstrap. I found one mega menu on Bootsnipp
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/mega-menu-slide-down-on-hover-with-carousel

but this menu only works in Bootsnipp, i have copied and pasted the code locally on my computer, but it's not working.
I have tried the same jquery, bootstrap.min.css bootstrap.min.js files but still its not working.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The scripts are called using `//` which indicates to use the same protocol as the page they are called on (`http` or `https`). Since it's neither locally, you must indicate the protocol manually.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I have tried using // , http and https still it's not working.

Comment: Please, post you code here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including the files directly have you tried linking to a CDN? Sometimes when I'm having issues I switch to this and it helps.

One that is use is:

https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Hope this helps.